# What is the best way to parse a millisecond date time in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What would be the next best thing for `strptime` when we have the datetime string with millisseconds?

Given:

```
"30/03/09 16:31:32.121"
```

we can't use the regular strptime because `struct tm` doesn't store millisseconds. Is there a new class that can achieve this?

Comment: [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) is C++11 but mirrors `strptime`'s specification. Do you need to store the milliseconds, or do you only need to display it?

Comment: My goal is to store this date time in a chrono timepoint, so I do need it to be parsed and stored.

Comment: With .1214 you are not asking for milliseconds, but for 1/10 milliseconds, or 100 microseconds.

Comment: Edited :) but I would like a general solution if possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would parse these fields manually (reading into int and double for the seconds), then use [days_from_civil](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) to convert the year/month/day into a `chrono::system_clock::time_point`:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t(days(days_from_civil(y, m, d)));
```

where `days` is:

```
using days = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>;
```

Then you can add to that the hours, minutes and seconds.  To handle the fractional seconds you'll need to do a slight dance:

```
double s;
your_stream >> s;  // 32.121
using namespace std::chrono;
duration<double> dsecs(s);
seconds sec = duration_cast<seconds>(dsecs);
milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(dsecs - sec);
t += sec + ms;
```

If you prefer, use [`round` from here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) for your milliseconds conversion:

```
milliseconds ms = round<milliseconds>(dsecs - sec);
```

`duration_cast` is truncate towards zero.  There are other rounding modes: floor, round, ceil, [at this link](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html).

Wrap it all up in a neat function for easy reuse. :-)

The above code all assumes UTC.  If your date/time that you are parsing is known to be offset from UTC, you can add/subtract that offset.  All known implementations of `system_clock` track [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is seconds since 1970-01-01 in the UTC time zone.

**Update**

Since writing this answer I've developed a [more general library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) that the OP seemed to be seeking at that time.  It can parse a wide variety of sub second precisions directly into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream in{"30/03/09 16:31:32.121\n"
                          "30/03/09 16:31:32.1214"};
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    in >> date::parse("%d/%m/%y %T", tp);
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
    in >> date::parse(" %d/%m/%y %T", tp);
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
2009-03-30 16:31:32.121000
2009-03-30 16:31:32.121400
```

This library uses the same techniques and tools as I originally described, but is packaged up and ready to go as a single header library.

Comment: instead of using days_from_civil (yet another external lib) I used regular time_t to get the date part working :) I ended up using google:re2 to read the pattern since I wanted something a little more generic. Thanks

Comment: hi  Howard, codes updated compiled error: error: date.h:4324:9 converting to ‘date::weekday’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr date::weekday::weekday(unsigned int)’
         fields() = default;
         ^

Comment: @ZFY.  Thanks for the report!  This sounds like this issue with pre-gcc-5 platforms:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues/264

Comment: Do we have an interface to parse "30/03/09 16:31:32.121" to time_point without using the istringstream?

Comment: No, sorry.  However if you're willing to make simplifying assumptions such as limited error handling, ASCII, and "C" locale, it isn't hard to parse your own integral values from any char buffer (such as `string`): https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/ptz.h#L828-L838.  And then it is trivial to convert these integral values into a `system_clock`-based `time_point`:  `auto tp = sys_days{day{d}/m/y} + hours{h} + minutes{M} + seconds{s} + milliseconds{ms};`.